# Rails 3, mysql join tables and habtm

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I created 2 tables called products and brands and created a join table called brands_products via migration.

In each of the models I wrote the corresponding has_and_belongs_to_many setting.

In a form if have the following code:

```
<%= form_for(@product) do |f| %>
    <% if @product.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
        <h2><%= pluralize(@product.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this product from being saved:</h2>

        <ul>
            <% @product.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
            <li><%= msg %></li>
            <% end %>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <% end %>

    <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :name %><br />
        <%= f.text_field :name %>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :brand %><br />
        <%= f.text_field (what to write?) %>
    </div>
    <div class="actions">
        <%= f.submit %>
    </div>
    <% end %>
```

I don't know how to add a brand to a product intuitively, like the way Rails usually works...any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to look at [accepts_nested_attributes_for](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html). You'll also want to look at [fields_for](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-fields_for). Without seeing more of your data model, it's hard to give a detailed answer.

Generally, it would look something like:

```
<%- f.fields_for :brands do |m| -%>
    <%= m.text_field :name %>
<%- end -%>
```

Comment: I think that's what I need. My model classes have barely anything in them. I'll try to implement it

Comment: In Rails 3, you might need a %= instead of %- in front of `fields_for`.

Comment: I think I found my problem, I should implement the "brands" and "brands_attributes" methods for it to work.